# Change names of elemnts thats are already names in a vector in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my vector

```
c("A~B", "C~D", "E~F", "G~H","I~J","K~L")
```

My original vector is much bigger than this. All I nees is to have an output like this:

```
c("A~B+time", "C~D+time", "E~F+time", "G~H+time","I~J+time","K~L+time")
```

Without doing manually.

Dplyr package could help me here?

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste0`

```
v <- c("A~B", "C~D", "E~F", "G~H","I~J","K~L")
paste0(v, "+time")
#[1] "A~B+time" "C~D+time" "E~F+time" "G~H+time" "I~J+time" "K~L+time"
```

or `sprintf`

```
sprintf("%s+time", v)
#[1] "A~B+time" "C~D+time" "E~F+time" "G~H+time" "I~J+time" "K~L+time"
```